# Maximum number of dbprocesses already allocated

Tags: sql-server-2005, delphi, delphi-7, bde

I'm running a Delphi application that uses BDE for database connection. Ocassionally (more often than I'd like) this error pops up when opening a query.

Googling for this error, most picks refer to MS SQLServer database, and speak about a dbsetmaxprocs function, which I can't seem to find.

So the question is: how can I prevent/correct this error? On which situations does this error rise and how can I avoid/work around it?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I leave some links I followed for reference.

- [Keep getting error: "Maximum number of DBPROCESSES already allocated".](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28718)
  *tried that, didn't work.*
- [SQL Error 10029 - Maximum number of DBPROCESSes already allocated](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Miscellaneous/Q_20843695.html)
  *can't find unclosed connections in my code.*
- [BUG: dbprocerrhandle Does Not Get Fired For Error 10029](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/q164/1/71.asp&NoWebContent=1&NoWebContent=1)
  *can't find dbsetmaxprocs anywhere.*
- [Same question at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/94543)

Comment: What data access components are you using (TTable, TQuery, etc)?  What is your target database?

Comment: We always use a custom component which inherits from TQuery. We then inherit from our component to handle specific data objects, but internal logic for basic operations (crud, queries) is already implemented.

Comment: Most probable problem is we're leaking connections somewhere (as suggested at Server Fault). The problem is: this error is happening at client's test environment (but not in production), and we cannot reproduce it here, so tracing this leak is impossible with current avalilable info.

Answer (score 1):

If you funnel all your TQuery connections through a central TDatabase component, you should only have one connection per application instance.  MSSQL's Profiler should help track down connections being opened.
It could even be a bug in your custom TQuery component.